# Sequelize association generate fields that do no exists

Tags: node.js, graphql, sequelize.js

I'm converting a PHP API to a GraphQL api. I'm using Sequelize as ORM package. I have two tables that I want to couple via a hasOne connection.

This is my AdvisoryService model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const AdvisoryService = sequelize.define(
        'advisoryService',
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
                field: 'id',
            },
            country: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                allowNull: true,
                references: {
                    model: 'system_country',
                    key: 'id',
                },
                field: 'country',
            },
          //REDACTED
        },
        {
            tableName: 'advisory_service',
            timestamps: false,
        },
    )
    AdvisoryService.associate = models => {
        AdvisoryService.hasOne(models.systemCountry, {
            as: 'Country',
            foreignKey: 'country',
        })
    }
    return AdvisoryService
}
```

And my systemCountry model:

```
/* jshint indent: 2 */

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define(
        'systemCountry',
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
                field: 'id',
            },
            oldId: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                allowNull: true,
                unique: true,
                field: 'old_id',
            },
            subcontinentId: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                allowNull: true,
                references: {
                    model: 'system_subcontinent',
                    key: 'id',
                },
                field: 'subcontinent_id',
            },
            code: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(2),
                allowNull: false,
                field: 'code',
            },
            longCode: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(3),
                allowNull: false,
                field: 'long_code',
            },
            currency: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
                allowNull: true,
                field: 'currency',
            },
            currencyCode: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
                allowNull: true,
                field: 'currency_code',
            },
            isEu: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
                allowNull: false,
                field: 'is_eu',
            },
            isAsean: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
                allowNull: false,
                field: 'is_asean',
            },
            isFragileWb: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
                allowNull: false,
                field: 'is_fragile_wb',
            },
            isFragilePf: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
                allowNull: false,
                field: 'is_fragile_pf',
            },
            isFragileOecd: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
                allowNull: false,
                field: 'is_fragile_oecd',
            },
            title: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
                allowNull: false,
                field: 'title',
            },
            latitude: {
                type: 'DOUBLE',
                allowNull: true,
                field: 'latitude',
            },
            longitude: {
                type: 'DOUBLE',
                allowNull: true,
                field: 'longitude',
            },
        },
        {
            tableName: 'system_country',
            timestamps: false,
        },
    )
}
```

It generates the following query:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `old_id` AS `oldId`, `subcontinent_id` AS `subcontinentId`, `code`, `long_code` AS `longCode`, `currency`, `currency_code` AS `currencyCode`, `is_eu` AS `isEu`, `is_asean` AS `isAsean`, `is_fragile_wb` AS `isFragileWb`, `is_fragile_pf` AS `isFragilePf`, `is_fragile_oecd` AS `isFragileOecd`, `title`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `country` FROM `system_country` AS `systemCountry` WHERE `systemCountry`.`country` = 1 LIMIT 1;
```

And throws the following error: SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'country' in 'field list'. Which I get, because there is no county field in the system_country table. I don't know why the association generates the country field. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You relation -

```
AdvisoryService.associate = models => {
    AdvisoryService.hasOne(models.systemCountry, {
        as: 'Country',
        foreignKey: 'country',
    })
}
```

Is defining the relationship with key - country hence its finding **country** in **systemCountry** table

Use the Following object in your relation definition -

```
{as: "Country", foreignKey: "OtherTableColumn", sourceKey: "SameTableColumn"}
```